# systemd service can't access user home

Tags: systemd

I am trying to setup a systemd service on Ubuntu 15.04 (and Debian 8). I have a program `/home/testuser/server/prrserver`. My systemd service is configured to run `prrserver` as `testuser:testuser`. What the `prrserver` does is start a new process `/home/testuser/server/prrproc` which reads some files in `/home/testuser/server/data`. What is interesting is that `prrserver` starts OK and `prrproc` starts OK but `prrproc` complains that there is no such file `/home/testuser/server/data/foo` which otherwise exists. If I start my server from the command line, it finds the file. Any idea what could be wrong? Maybe when `prrserver` forks a new process, the new process doesn't run as `testuser` anymore and for some reason can't access the testuser directory (even though it's permission allow this)?

```
[Unit]
Description=PRR Server

[Service]
Type=simple
User=testuser
Group=testuser
ExecStart=/home/testuser/server/prrserver

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The status is something like this:

```
systemctl status prrserver.service
    â prrserver.service - PRR Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/prrserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since mÃ¥n 2015-05-25 14:50:42 CEST; 1min 2s ago
 Main PID: 21205 (prrserver)
   CGroup: /system.slice/prrserver.service
           ââ21205 /bin/sh /home/testuser/server/prrserver
           ââ22101 /bin/sh /home/testuser/server/prrproc

maj 25 14:50:42 ubuntu-dev systemd[1]: Started PRR Server.
maj 25 14:50:42 ubuntu-dev systemd[1]: Starting PRR Server...
maj 25 14:50:53 ubuntu-dev prrserver[21205]: PRR Server started listening on port 10239
```

Note that the main process `prrserver` launches the `prrproc` processes and the problem is with the `prrproc` processes so the status of the service is green.

Comment: Is it starting as root? The file not found error is from Journalctl?

Comment: I log in as root and then start the service. The forked process dies and its log file I can see that the reason is because it did not find the file.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and _show_ people (a) the service unit contents, and (b) the output of `systemctl status prserver.service` when run as the superuser (or an `adm` user).

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: This is a problem only when started at boot? The `/home` may not yet be mounted at that time. Also, in systemd, there is a concept of *user* and *system* ***sessions*** - which *might* be a problem. Another possible problem is whether or not systemd is running the service in a private mount namespace - I cannot recall under what conditions it does so, but definitely in some situations systemd will expose only specific sections of the mount tree to services. But it's the Wanted.By that is the problem, I think. You should add a `Wants` for `local.fs.target`.

Comment: Using encrypted home?

Comment: No, /home is not mounted or encrypted. For some reason the forked processes don't get access to it. This is really frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

In theory it could be private mount namespace.  It's a security feature.  I guess you could try ruling it out with

```
ProtectHome=off
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not help :(

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this problem as well and found no answer. This is what I was able to achieve, but please suggest better alternatives if you can.

*The method I describe here doesn't exactly fit @RegedUser00x 's use case, but might lead you in the right direction.*
*In particular, **my solution won't respect the file system permission, which might not be desirable**.*

The only way I was able to make it work is by adding the capability: `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` [(ref)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).

> `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH` Bypass file read permission checks and directory read and execute permission checks".

```
[Unit]
# ...

[Service]
# ...

# Disallow system modification
ProtectSystem=true

# Restrict access to the home folder while only allowing certain folders
ProtectHome=tmpfs
BindPaths=/home/myuser/useful_folder /home/myuser/useful_file

# CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH Bypass file read permission checks and directory
# read and execute permission checks;
CapabilityBoundingSet= CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
# ...
```